# Wordpress 403 forbidden error only for specific menu

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I move my site from 1 server to other, now only 1 WP menu from 3 returns a forbidden error.
On my WordPress everything working fine except Menu.

**403 Forbidden error only when press "save menu" button**

If page link is

- example.com/blog/wp-admin/nav-menus.php `// on menu save, it save successfully.`
- example.com/blog/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`?action=edit&menu=2` `// forbidden error on save`

There are 3 menu in WP, 2 are working fine, When i press Save

[image]

**DEBUG**

- I delete all plugins, all plugin files, but issue same.
- I change theme but the issue same.
- I delete .htaccess so WP creates auto, but issue same.
- Other things are working fine, so its means there is no issue in file permissions.
- `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` // no debug logs or errors

**Server:**

- WP install on Dedicated server, full access on WHM/cpanel
- Move from server to server with the help of Duplicator Plugin

Please help how can I trace the issue and fix it?

**Forbidden Page/ Header**
.
[image]

Comment: Is your new environment behind a web application firewall?

Comment: Also add your request and response headers from when you click the save button and you receive the forbidden message.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson Kindly check new updated question.

Comment: Don't set the permissions to 777. Can you please include the post data that's sent in the request?

Comment: current file permission 755, and change wp-content/upload and all files and sub-folder to 777, but forbidden issue not solve.

Comment: Then set it back to 755 first , (so not the permission problem in upload folders)

Comment: Please check the permission of this file: /blog/wp-admin/nav-menus.php (set it as read and execute permitted)

Comment: @KenLee nav-menu permission was 644 i change to 744 and 774 both not work, set back to 644, all files permission is 644 others are working except nav-menu

Comment: try changing to 755 for that particular file please

Comment: 755 for nav-menu also not work, i try to clean cache or browser, still same issue.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson post data is too big, you can check here,
https://scrapersite.com/blog/wp-admin/nav-menus.php ID: temp, password: temp and nav-menu permission is 755

Comment: Is there a possibility this site or server has been compromised recently?

Comment: NO. it is new user account and upload WP first time on server.

Comment: Here's what I can tell you, if that forbidden message isn't coming from the htaccess file, then it could be in the server's configuration (host or vhost for instance). The reason I ask if its compromised is because I tried similar POST requests with query strings on other pages and they work fine, which implies that something is targeting post backs for that specific url (or post/get parameters). A WAF could also do this, but it doesn't look like I see one. If it's a brand new install, then I'd try to get into the server conf files. I think that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: And, how is it that a new site has over 600 comments already? I feel like there's a part of the story that's missing here.

Comment: 600 comments from other domain. like i copy example1.com and upload files on example2.com and i will delete all data.. if i delete menu and create new menu return forbidden message.

Comment: Oh, new server, old site. That doesn't preclude that something was compromised on the old site. In fact, your new server could be protecting itself from something the web application is trying to do with compromised code (or database content).

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson i install Fresh NEW WP in a different folder, and the issue is same for menu. other things are working fine.